# Solution to divide M in N where M in N such that M = A x Y where no two N contains same A

Tags: c++, algorithm

A example here :

Consider M no of containers 
N total no of fruits
A type of fruit eg apple, orange
Y no of fruits of same type..

So 5 containers

100 fruits
32 apples, 7 oranges, 17 watermelon, 6 pineapple, 8 guava, 15 banana, 15 papaya

papaya + pineapple - 21
banana + oranges - 22
apples - 32
watermelon - 17
guava  8

**Main priority is no two container should have same fruit** ..so cant divide apples into two container..

also shouldn't be too many types of fruit in single container
like guava + pineapple + oranges in one

Sorry for bad editing

**Can somebody name the type of problem and algorithm to be used in this..**

Further suggestions to improve the question are open ..Not a computer Science student

**PS: not needing a solution here only type of problem and algorithm used and does it fit exactly in this scenario**

Comment: please also reason why is this being downvoted

Comment: I simply do not understand what you are trying to achieve, furthermore your case seems too specific to be categorized as a problem of type X. Try to look in optimization problems or so, seems somewhat close to what you are trying to do. Also, a minimum of code should be provided, we are not a code generator, nor free programmers.

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody name the type of problem and algorithm to be used in this..

The type of algorithm is called the knapsack algorithm, and it is usually combined with greedy selection for each container (the greed will depend on your selection criteria).

Edit: Actually, this doesn't fit any standard algorithm *exactly*, but you will find elements of the knapsack and greedy in it. All in all it sounds like a custom problem.

Comment: But it's not exactly knapsack considering shouldn't be too many types of fruit in single container.. part..

Comment: But it's not exactly knapsack considering shouldn't be too many types of fruit in single container.. part.. Also it's greedy only when you are working on limited data.. Or part of data.. Here you have the exact value if all the variables M N A and Y